# LINQ select where item is not in list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

i need to insert items that are not in db. so i'm trying to run the following (which doesn't work):

```
 foreach(var rep in model.Reps.Where(x => x.Value != 
    this.dictionaryItemRepository.List().Select(y => y.Value)))
```

where model.Reps is:

```
 public ICollection<DictionaryItemBrand> Reps { get; set; }
```

returned from model binder

I'm trying to do a foreach loop -> **select all items from model.Reps that do NOT yet exist in repository.**

how can i do it?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be it.

```
var notInRepo = from rep in model.Reps
                where (!this.dictionaryItemRepository.Contains(rep.Value))
                select rep.Value;
```